# Meaning of the Notation $T: [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1]$?

Tags: functions, notation

I'm not completely sure what the following notation means:

$T: [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1]$.

$T$ is a transformation. I guess in the context of the notation, $T$ is basically a transformation function I guess. I approximate this transformation function in a historical time period and use it for a future time period. Does this notation mean, that $T$ is defined for a closed intervall between 0 and 1 and that using $T$ on a future period doesn't change that fact? So to speak, $T$ is also defined for a closed intervall between 0 and 1 for the future period?

I thank everybody in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transformation"? What you see is a classical notation for functions $f:X\to Y$. It's just that here $X=Y=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation
$$
f:X\to Y
$$
is used to mean "$f$ is a function which takes elements from $X$ as input and gives elements of $Y$ as output". Calling it things like mapping or transformation doesn't change this (at least not without more context). $X$ is called the domain, and $Y$ is called the codomain.

So in your case, $T$ is a function which can take any element of $[0,1]$ as input and give you an element of $[0,1]$ in return. So $T(0)$ makes sense, as does $T(1), T(0.5)$ and $T(\pi/4)$. And these values are all somewhere in the codomain, i.e. somewhere between $0$ and $1$.

On the other hand, $T(-1), T(2.3)$ or $T(\sqrt 5)$ do not make sense, as $-1, 2.3$ and $\sqrt 5$ are not elements of the domain $[0,1]$

Comment: The words "mapping" and "transformation" are usually used to change how we look at the function. It's still the same thing, but instead of thinking of it in terms of value-output pairings, it's thought of more as a ... transformation.

Comment: Thank you for that great explanation. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that $T$ is a map from the set $[0,1]$ into itself.